# Reducing TIC-TAC TOE State Space by using Symmetry in Artificial Intelligence

Tags: problem-solving, game-theory, artificial-intelligence, searching

Im learning Heuristics in AI.I see that for brute force search there are 9! states.But the textbook says that first 3 levels are reduced by symmetry.How does that work?

[image]

Comment: Rotational symmetry here. Notice that X in the top left is the same as X in any corner (at this stage)

Comment: okay.. i get it.

Comment: why question is downvoted.

Comment: it may be because of the low picture quality. I don't know, I think the question is fine as is.

Comment: Because you've shown no effort at understanding it yourself, and it's really simple. You can see that there are 9 places X can go, yet 3 are shown and didn't see the pattern.

Comment: @AlecTeal If i could have think that much,i should not have posted this over here.

Comment: @5xum Yeah... thanks

Comment: Even without symmetry, $9!$ is too big as games can end early. Actually the reduction for the whole game can be substantially improved, easily by a factor of $8$ with the rotational and reflective symmetries of a square, and possibly further.   See discussion at the end of http://www.se16.info/hgb/tictactoe.htm and in http://www.mathrec.org/old/2002jan/solutions.html

Comment: @Henry Thanks.. i will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position

```
x |  | 
__|__|__
  |  |
__|__|__
  |  |
  |  |
```

Is equivalent to

```
  |  | x 
__|__|__
  |  |
__|__|__
  |  |
  |  |
```

and

```
  |  | 
__|__|__
  |  |
__|__|__
  |  |
x |  |
```

and

```
  |  | 
__|__|__
  |  |
__|__|__
  |  |
  |  | x
```

So you don't have to look at each individual position, thus reducing the number of positions to analyse by a factor of $4$.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: i only upvoted.. my question is also downvoted.

Comment: @techno I am not accusing you, but I would like the downvoter to explain how my answer is bad and needs a downvote.

Comment: yeah .. i know.. just sayin my part :)

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate or flip the board from any other configuration to match one of those three.

For example, if you moved in bottom center, flip the board from top to bottom to get the third configuration on the second row.

Or if you moved in the bottom right, you could rotate the board 180 degrees to get the first configuration in the second row.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reduction in the third row, where there are two x's and one o. It is not important in which order the x's appear, so one can reduce by a factor of 2.

Comment: okay.. thanks..